# specify random effects in lme4

Tags: r, lme4, random-effects

I would like to ask for your help in specifying the random effects of a model I have been working on in lme4. I have data from a field survey. The objective of the study is to relate wing size (respond variable) with habitat (exploratory variable, categorical variable with 2 levels). We performed a paired design by sampling 50 individuals of 3 species in a simple habitat and the same 3 species (n=50 again) in a complex habitat in a region. We replicated that in 20 regions. I am both interested in the species specific effects and community effects. 
For running the analyses per species is this model correct?

```
modela<-lmer(Wingsize~Habitat+(1|Region))
```

For community wide effects is this model correct?

```
modelb<-lmer(Wingsize~Habitat+(1|Region/Habitat/Species))
```

Schematic (from [on-hold CrossValidated question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/419693/specify-random-effects-in-lme4):

[image]

[Short Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWhDQ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I would not use `Habitat` both as fixed effect *and* group level effect, because then you have a "perfect" correlation between group level and fixed effects. Rather, I would use `Habitat` only as fixed effect:

```
modelb<-lmer(Wingsize~Habitat+(1|Region/Species))
```